# ScrollableResults into List reference

Tags: java, hibernate, collections

I have to convert Scrollable Results reference into List reference. Is it  possible?
When I tried to convert,i am getting exception as `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.impl.ScrollableResultsImpl cannot be cast to java.util.List.` 
Please provide solution  for  this issue....

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast a `ScrollableResults` object into a `List`. Casting does not automatically convert objects for you. You will need to create a new `List` yourself, then iterate through the `ScrollableResults` and add each row to the `List` yourself:

```
ScrollableResults result = ...;

List<...> list = new ArrayList<>();

while (result.next()) {
    list.add(result.get());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much...  List<Object[]> orderList = new ArrayList(); and iterated and i stored  scorllable  result in  orderList..as per my code requirement I have to type cast in OrderDTO  refrence.. i mean that  OrderDTO thisOrder = null; and  in the itreation i have to convert  this way  thisOrder = (OrderDTO)orderIterator.next();.. but it giving run time exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to ,,,,.order.db.OrderDTO

Comment: Again, you cannot cast any arbitrary type to any other arbitrary type. You're trying to cast an `Object[]` to an `OrderDTO`. An array of objects is simply not an `OrderDTO`, so you can't cast it like that. You need to write code yourself to convert it.

Comment: could I  use  List<OrderDTO> orderList= new ArrayList() and  iterating and storing scrollable result into orderList ....

Comment: Yes, but each row in the `ScrollableResults` consists of an array of objects (with one object for each column in the row). You will need to convert those columns to an `OrderDTO` object yourself.

Comment: I tried ... but the compiler simply said that cannot find symbol
  symbol  : method add(java.lang.Object[])

Comment: Your `List` has to be a `List<OrderDTO>`. Then, inside the loop, get the row: `Object[] row = result.get();`. Then create a new `OrderDTO` and fill it with the columns of the row, as appropriate. Then add the `OrderDTO` object to the list.

Answer (score 1):

`org.hibernate.impl.ScrollableResultsImpl` does not implement the `java.util.List` interface. So you can not cast it to List. 
You should scroll the object by calling next method and get the row values by  `ScrollableResultsImpl#getCurrentRow()` and then insert into your List.

```
ScrollableResults sResult = ...;

List<Object[]> list = any list implementation; like ArrayList/LinkedList...

while (sResult.next()) {
    list.add(result.getCurrentRow());
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see in the Hibernate API documentation there is no `getCurrentRow()` method in `ScrollableResults`. There is a `get()` method though.

Comment: yes you are. Its in `AbstractScrollableResults` and implemented in `ScrollableResultsImpl` [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/impl/ScrollableResultsImpl.html#getCurrentRow())